# Blazor and Dependency Injection System.objectDisposedException

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app.

I am using EF framework with Dependency injection. In most cases it works well with no errors. However, I am doing a UI update on a timer, and I get thrown a

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'ApplicationDbContext'.'

This is the Code, on the Blazor page it works well for the page load, and then maybe about 10/20 refreshes, then it crashes out.

```cs
@code {
    public bool Showmap;

    Machine_Device Device = new Machine_Device();

    [Parameter]
    public string DeviceID { get; set; }

    System.Threading.Timer timer;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (DeviceID != null)
        {
            var t = await JsonAction.GetLatest_FullData_MachineDevice(DeviceID);
            Device = t;
        }

        timer =  new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateUI, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private async void UpdateUI(object state)
    {
        var t = await JsonAction.GetLatest_FullData_MachineDevice(DeviceID);

        Device = t;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
```

In my Startup I have set the AppicationDBcontext to Transient - I did research on this.
I also set the DeviceJsonActions () to Transient as well rather than scoped, in an attempt to resolve this error.

Startup

```cs
services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddTransient<DeviceJsonActions>(); (defined as JsonAction in BlazorPage)
```

In the DeviceJsonAction class it is defined as follows

```cs
public class DeviceJsonActions
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ClaimsPrincipal SignedInIdentity { get; set; }

    public DeviceJsonActions(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it maybe the timer executing after the component has been disposed.

```
@implements IDisposable

....

@code {
   ...

  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
    if(timer is not null) // C# 9.0
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be, but only when it's the old timer after a reconnect. And why would the DbContext be disposed then?  The error would have to be from the StateHasChanged call.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes I think this is why its a "intermittent" error.  Its only happening when the garbage collection has not completed and the UpdateUI has already been called on a thread.

Comment: No, the timer should keep the context (inside JsonAction) alive.

Comment: so it seems like this is the solution, the only thing i had to do was add `If{timer != null} then it seemed to work, been running 24 hours without a issue, not production but test, i will have to see. I also updated all the Libs to the Latest .net 5 RC Versions incl Entity Framework.

Comment: Sorry my answer was fairly abstract. Ill update it to include the better dispose pattern.

Comment: It's almost 2021. `timer?.Dispose();`